# Conditional Operator: ? : is not working in c

Tags: c, crash, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

I was working with conditionals in c. While coding I found that this code is not working

```
int x = 1;
printf(1>0? "%d",x : "0");
```

Now, 1 is obviously greater than 0. So the program should print the value of x. But it actually never prints anything!
I am using Codeblocks 17.12 and my compiler is MingW

Comment: Your output is a compiler error: https://ideone.com/kDz3Bi an error and a warning, to be correct.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings: *warning C4047: ':': 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'char [2]'*.

Comment: If that even cleanly compiles it's because you're not enabling warnings and/or not treating them as errors. `"0"` and `x` are completely different types, therefore the second expression in your [comma operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do) does not match the first for type compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

It is working as specified. Unfortunately, you are misusing it. You seem to expect that the condition check should produce one of two function invocations:

```
printf("%d",x);
printf("0");
```

That's now not how C works. You use  the conditional expression, so the result must be a single value, which translates to a single function argument. The comma you wrote is not the comma which is used to separate arguments to functions. It is the *comma operator*, which is an expression itself.

The semantics of the *expression* `"%d", x` is to evaluate `"%d"`, discard the result, and then evaluate `x`. `x` is the result of the expression with the comma operator.

Which means your function call is equivalent to

```
printf(1 > 0 ? x : "0");
```

You pass an integer where a pointer to a string is expected. A decent compiler should flag that with a warning at least, and if yours doesn't you need to give it the proper flags to warn you about this.

Comment: No way I could beat you on a phone keyboard : ( . Anyway have my +1.

Answer (score 2):

You have errors in your code.

Try this:

```
printf("%d", 1 > 0 ? x : 0);
```

I invite you to check the [printf documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) and some [ternary operator examples](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/ternary_operator_examples.htm) to better understand what is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
printf(1 < 0 ? "0": "%d",x);
```